# How to authenticate users and securely serve videos for them to watch?

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to prevent unauthorize users from being able to view video on my company internal website using laravel 4.2.

The videos are stored outside the document root. therefore, I need a way to serve the videos to the users.

I have a route that handles the request as follows:

```
Route::get('video/{name}', function($name){
    $type = explode('.', $name)[1];
    header("Content-Type: video/$type");
    $file = "c:\\xampp5-4\\intranet\public\\$name";
    readfile($file);//I tried return Response::download($pathToFile); the video download, but it does not play
    die();//$this is a simple example of the many things I've tried
})->before('auth');
```

It works in pure php, but for some reason its not working in laravel.

Comment: Did you get any error when you use `Response::download($pathToFile);`?

Comment: No I didn't get any errors. It downloaded the file very quickly but I am unable to play the video. It might have something to do with the headers.